# Load the page faster loadHTMLfile

Tags: php, performance, load

Ive added this php script to my websit, but it makes the web load very slow.
Is there any way to make it faster?

```
                   <?php 
                        $doc = new DOMDocument;
                        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
                        $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
                        $doc->recover = true;
                        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                        $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://lolbuilder.net/aatrox');
                        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
                        $query = "//div[@class='col-sm-6']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]";
                        $entries = $xpath->query($query);
                        echo ($entries->item(0)->textContent);
                    ?>
```

The script bassically takes some info from another site and outputs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script makes another request, there is not much you can do to speed that up. If the result doesn't change (often), maybe cache it to avoid external requests

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get page with curl, then pass it to DOMDocument.

here an example about this.

http://community.sitepoint.com/t/domdocument-vs-curl-plain-text/80518

Answer (score 0):

I would try to load the file locally, versus thru the internet. Try timing your DOM query too to see if that is causing slow speeds.